# React login form sends empty data to the backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, prisma

I had this well working frontend - backend setup, until I decided to make my code more clean and added controllers. Now my backend receives an object with no data when a user is trying to login and I have no clue where the problem is..

**== API ==**

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require("cors");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

dotenv.config();

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Testing')
})

app.use("/api/auth", require("./routes/authRoutes"));

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("app is running!")
});
```

authRoutes.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const authControllers = require('../controllers/authControllers');

router.post('/register', authControllers.register);
router.post('/login', authControllers.login);
// router.post("/logout");

module.exports = router
```

authController.js

```
const { PrismaClient } = require('@prisma/client');
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const prisma = new PrismaClient();
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const login = async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  try {
      const { email, password } = req.body;

      const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({ where: { email: email } });
      if (!user) {return res.status(401).json({ error: "Password or email is incorrect." });}

      const isValidPassword = bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);
      if (!isValidPassword) {return res.status(401).json({ error: "Password or email is incorrect." });}

      const accesToken = jwt.sign({ userId: user.id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: "3h" });

      res.status(200).json({
        status: "OK",
        message: "Login succes",
        token: accesToken,
        user
    });
  } 
  catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      res.status(401).json({ error: "Password or email is incorrect." });
  }
};

const register = async (req, res) => {
  try {
      const { username, password, email } = req.body;

      const existingUser = await prisma.user.find({ where: { email } });
      if (existingUser) { return res.status(409).json({ error: "This email is already registered." }) }

      const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
      const newUser = await prisma.user.create({
        data: {
          username,
          password: hashedPassword,
          email,
        },
      });

      const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user.id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: "3h" });
      res.json({ token });
  } 
  catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal server error." });
  }
};

module.exports = { register, login };
```

**== APP ==**

loginform.js

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
/* eslint-disable react-hooks/exhaustive-deps */
import './login.css'
import InputField from '../InputField';
import Button from '../Button';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import ErrorField from '../ErrorField';
import useLogin from '../../../hooks/useLogin';

const LoginForm = () => {

    // Login component

    const [disable, setDisable] = useState(true);

    const { login, error, formValues, setFormValues } = useLogin()

    const handleChange = async (e) => {
        setFormValues({
            ...formValues,
            [e.currentTarget.name]: e.currentTarget.value
        })
    }

    const submitLoginForm = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        await login();
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setDisable(!(formValues.email && formValues.password))
    }, [formValues.password, formValues.email]);

    return (
        <div className="login">
            <img src="./logo.svg" />
            <h2>Login</h2>
            {error && <ErrorField className="form-feedback show" value={error} />}
            <InputField placeholder="Email" className="form-input" name="email" type="text" value={formValues.email || ''} onChange={handleChange} />
            <InputField placeholder="Password" className="form-input" name="password" type="password" value={formValues.password || ''} onChange={handleChange} />
            <Button type="submit" input="LOG IN" className={`form-button ${disable ? 'disabled' : ''}`} disabled={disable} onClick={submitLoginForm}/>
            <Link to='/signup' className='signup-link'>No account? Sign up here!</Link>
        </div>
    )
}

export default LoginForm;
```

useLoginHook.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "../config/axios";
import useAuthContext from "./useAuthContext";

const useLogin = () => {
    const [error, setError] = useState(null)
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(null)
    const { dispatch } = useAuthContext()

    const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState({
        email: "",
        password: "",
    })

    const emptyFormValues = {
        email: "",
        password: "",
    }

    const navigate = useNavigate()

    const login = async (formValues) => {
        
        setIsLoading(true)         
        setError(null)
        
        try {
           const response = await axios.post('api/auth/login', formValues);
           console.log(response.data);
           localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token)
           dispatch({type: 'LOGIN', payload: response})
           setIsLoading(false)
           navigate("/");

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.response.data)
            setFormValues(emptyFormValues)
            setIsLoading(false)
            setError(error.response.data.error)
        }
    }

    return { login, isLoading, error, setError, formValues, setFormValues }
}

export default useLogin;
```

Comment: Hello you can check if your frontend is sending any data to backend when going to Network tab on DevTools section, click on the login request and check if it's sending the data correctly. If it's sending it right, then the problem is on backend, you can use a simple middleware after the line "app.use(bodyParser.json());" (use "app.use(express.json())") to check every request sent to your backend, add this : "app.use((req,res,next) => {console.log(req.body); next()})" this will print the body of every request and then procceed to the current request. So you can debug what's happening easier.

Comment: Where exactly do I have to put that console.log? In my index.js at the backend?

Comment: That line is on the backend, the first file you sent here

Comment: this returns undefined..

Comment: @Stef-Verniers - I noticed that in the `login` method used to log in users are not receiving the proper arguments when called in the `submitLoginForm` handler, can you check this out? If possible, add an [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) example to help you out better.

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAli, I saw that indeed I didn't passed this so once I did that, it worked again. Thank you for pointing out the origin of my problem!!

Answer (score 0):

If the React login form is sending empty data to the backend, there might be a few potential causes:

1. Form Input Fields: Make sure the form input fields are properly connected to the `formValues` state variables. Ensure that the `value` attribute of each input field is correctly bound to its corresponding state variable (`email` and `password`).
2. Form Submission: Verify that the form submission event handler is correctly implemented. When the form is submitted, ensure that you prevent the default form submission behavior (using `event.preventDefault()`) and properly handle the data before sending it to the backend.
3. State Update: Double-check that the `setFormValues` function is correctly updating the state. When the user enters values in the input fields, the state variables `email` and `password` should be updated with the new values. Confirm that the `onChange` event handlers are correctly configured to update the state variables.

Based on the code you provided, it seems that the problem lies in the `useLogin` custom hook implementation. Here are the issues I identified:

1. In the `LoginForm.js` file, the `useLogin` hook is imported and used. However, it's missing the necessary dependency imports from React. Please ensure that you have imported `React` at the beginning of the file:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
```

2. In the `useLogin` hook, you defined `formValues` as a state variable, but when invoking the `login` function, you're not passing the `formValues` as an argument. Update the `login` function signature in the `useLogin` hook to accept the `formValues` as an argument:

```
const login = async () => {
  // ...
};
```

3. In the `loginForm.js` file, you're invoking the `login` function without passing any arguments. Since the `useLogin` hook defines `login` without arguments, you need to update the `submitLoginForm` function to pass the `formValues`:

```
const submitLoginForm = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  await login(formValues);
};
```

By making these modifications, you should be able to pass the correct `formValues` to the `login` function and resolve the issue.